# why does my itunes library while playing music, have a pause in the playing?

Tags: itunes

I am currently having an issue while listening to music via my library in itunes on my laptop. The songs will play but they have a pause/skip effect to them every so many seconds while in play mode. I cannot seem to figure out what is going on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you running Google Chrome at the same time? That will eat processor power.

Answer (score 0):

As of recently iTunes has become a 64 bit program only (**[Source](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1614)**), so if you have 32 bits then it will either run very poorly or won't start up.  So if you have a 32 bit computer I would recommend not using iTunes.

It could also be that your audio card/audio driver is outdated or needs an update.  Make sure you have the latest versions of drivers.

Because you didn't give any computer information I could not answer fully, but I did my best.

If your issue is iTunes is freezing completely, it is probably the fact that you have 32 bits.

If your issue is the sound cutting out and iTunes continuing, it is probably an outdated audio card/driver.

Comment: iTunes '64 only' is for Mac OS, Windows still comes in 32 & 64 bit flavours. A 64-bit app would neither install nor run at all on a 32-bit OS, so that cannot be the diagnosis.

Comment: @Tetsujin `"iTunes is now a full 64-bit application on 64-bit editions of Windows 8, 7, and Vista."` [Source](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1614)

Comment: Windows System Requirements - 
Windows XP Service Pack 3 or later, 32-bit editions of Windows Vista, Windows 7, or Windows 8 - 
64-bit editions of Windows Vista, Windows 7, or Windows 8 require the iTunes 64-bit installer [source](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/) My earlier comment still stands.

Comment: @Tetsujin That is weird how that information is conflicting... but the source I have is the changelog for iTunes 12.1, and it was posted Jan 29, 2015.  Maybe Apple needs to fix one of these pages

Comment: It's not really conflicting. Previously you could DL either 32 or 64-bit to use on a 64-bit OS. That no longer appears to be the case, but the 32-bit still exists, for 32-bit OS. The point I was trying to make is that though a 32-bit app will install & run on 64-bit OS [subject to that recent change] it is not possible at all to run a 64-bit app on a 32-bit OS, so that could not be the OP's issue.

Comment: @Tetsujin oh ok, I see what you are saying.  I am still a little confused because iTunes is running as a 64 bit application on my computer right now but when you go to download iTunes it says 32 bit, but at the same time the changelog says 64 bit only